# Argument passing to Java Socket Program

Tags: java, sockets, url, arguments

is it possible to send argument to java socket like we do in url argument passing

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX?id=d1948b485d6
```

I have application which broadcast message from XXXX1 to XXXX10 port and every port i have assigned to specific user , so i want to restrict user from to access any other port .

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX?id=d1948b485d6 by using unique id was decided to validate user with port,id buts its not possible so any other way do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is a unique feature of web page access and can't be used with regular sockets. It can be used with servlets, though, because they are basically web pages.

Edit: Now that the question has been revised, I can now answer the underlying question much better than the original question. It is not a good idea to assign each user a port. Then you are limited to about 64000 users. Instead, the user should transmit authentication information with each request, or transmit it when opening the connection and then use only that connection.

Comment: Actually I want to avoid illegal access to other port of my server by user , because its possible that user can change port number and will try to access another port .. any other way to do so.